# Image upload in form using input type text

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, image

I'm kind of new to web designing.
I'm making a project on ruby on rails.I want a form for particular listings in which i can upload images for that listings.Images is in other table.Now one way is i can use file upload but when i edit any listings,it will show file field empty.So, i'm thinking to use input type text and associate a browse button and javascript for uploading image.Besides,this i also want javacsript function for adding new image,editing image(particular) or deleting image(particular).So,as u see its kind of giving pain in brain.please explain what to do easily and step wise.Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Thats rails casts helps for you

http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload (PRO Cast)

Comment: i'm making entire form in html(its easier for me than ruby).please tell according to that. All i want is simple text that user enter url using browse.and that image be uploaded.(also additional functionality for adding new,deleting,editing,etc.).And on my side i want that image to be saved in assets/images/example.jpg and in table of images the address so formed be saved.... i'm not getting anywhere.I think its simple but i'm not understanding.plz help.its important

Comment: Sorry, I never thought about this question, how to do it only for HTML. I dont know a way to make this on HTML.
Need ruby skills to save photo to directory, to save string of this image.

Answer (score 0):

A text field cannot mimic an input type file the way you describe it.

You may also wanna take a look at this post about image upload with HTML, rails and paperclip
[How to POST files from HTML5 Drag-Drop to a Rails 3 App & Paperclip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764966/how-to-post-files-from-html5-drag-drop-to-a-rails-3-app-paperclip)

Comment: i'm making entire form in html(its easier for me than ruby).please tell according to that. All i want is simple text that user enter url using browse.and that image be uploaded.(also additional functionality for adding new,deleting,editing,etc.).And on my side i want that image to be saved in assets/images/example.jpg and in table of images the address so formed be saved.... i'm not getting anywhere.I think its simple but i'm not understanding.plz help.its important

Answer (score 0):

The awesome file attachment ruby gem `Paperclip` will do that for you.

If you are new to these I strongly suggest watching these two screencasts from Railscasts:

1) http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

2) http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

**Image delete**

[Delete an image with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343937/delete-an-image-with-paperclip)

**Image Upload**

The form add the actual form fields that will be used to upload the images using `fields_for`. Also edit the form_for call and mark the form as multipart so it can accept file uploads.

```
<% form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

…

<% f.fields_for :user_images do |builder| %>

<% if builder.object.new_record? %>

<%= builder.label :caption, "Image Caption" %>
<%= builder.text_field :caption %>

<%= builder.label :photo, "Image File" %>
<%= builder.file_field :photo %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: i'm making entire form in html(its easier for me than ruby).please tell according to that.
All i want is simple text that user enter url using browse.and that image be uploaded.(also additional functionality for adding new,deleting,editing,etc.).And on my side i want that image to be saved in assets/images/example.jpg and in table of images the address so formed be saved.... i'm not getting anywhere.I think its simple but i'm not understanding.plz help.its important